Automate grants on Procedures and Functions in Snowflake procedure
I am running the following procedure to obtain the SQL for grants to roles on a database:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DBMGT.REFRESHES.GET_DB_GRANTS(dbname VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE ()
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
DECLARE
    qry VARCHAR;
    v_sql varchar;
    DB_SCHEMA_PATH varchar default '';

    
    C1 CURSOR FOR SELECT PRIVILEGE, GRANTED_ON, TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, NAME, GRANTED_TO, GRANTEE_NAME 
    FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_ROLES 
    WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = ?;
    
BEGIN

     IF (NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM "SNOWFLAKE"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."DATABASES"
        WHERE DATABASE_NAME = upper(:dbname)
    ) )THEN
        LET rs RESULTSET := (select 'Source database does not exist');
        RETURN table(rs);
    END IF;

    CREATE or REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE DBMGT.REFRESHES.GRANT_STORE(SQL_QRY VARCHAR);

    OPEN C1 USING(:DBNAME);

    FOR obj IN C1 DO 
        IF (obj.GRANTED_ON = 'DATABASE') THEN 
            qry := 'GRANT ' || obj.PRIVILEGE || ' ON ' || obj.GRANTED_ON || ' ' || dbname || ' TO ' || obj.GRANTED_TO || ' ' || obj.GRANTEE_NAME ;
        elseif (obj.GRANTED_ON = 'SCHEMA') then
            qry := 'GRANT ' || obj.PRIVILEGE || ' ON ' || obj.GRANTED_ON || ' ' || dbname || '.' || obj.TABLE_SCHEMA ||' TO ' || obj.GRANTED_TO || ' ' || obj.GRANTEE_NAME ;
        ELSEIF (obj.GRANTED_ON IN ('PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION')) THEN
          qry := 'GRANT ' || obj.PRIVILEGE || ' ON ' || obj.GRANTED_ON || ' ' || dbname || '.' || obj.TABLE_SCHEMA || '.' || obj.NAME || ' TO ' || obj.GRANTED_TO || ' ' || obj.GRANTEE_NAME ;
        else
        qry := 'GRANT ' || obj.PRIVILEGE || ' ON ' || obj.GRANTED_ON || ' ' || dbname || '.' || obj.TABLE_SCHEMA || '.' || obj.NAME || ' TO ' || obj.GRANTED_TO || ' ' || obj.GRANTEE_NAME ;
        
        END IF;      

        if (obj.PRIVILEGE = 'OWNERSHIP') THEN
        qry := qry || ' COPY CURRENT GRANTS' ;
    end if;

    qry := qry || ' ;';
   
    insert into DBMGT.REFRESHES.GRANT_STORE values (:qry);
        
    END FOR;
    CLOSE C1;

    LET rs RESULTSET := (select * from DBMGT.REFRESHES.GRANT_STORE);

    RETURN table(rs);
END;
$$;

It is working fine for most objects but it is having problems for functions and procedures, for example, if I run this script on TESTDB
 CALL DBMGT.REFRESHES.GET_DB_GRANTS('TESTDB');

It procedures the following result for the procedure
LOG_ETL_STATS(JOB_NAME VARCHAR, SOURCE_TABLE VARCHAR, TARGET_TABLE VARCHAR, APPLICATION_NAME VARCHAR):


GRANT OWNERSHIP ON PROCEDURE 
TESTDB.OPERATIONS.LOG_ETL_STATS(JOB_NAME VARCHAR, SOURCE_TABLE VARCHAR, TARGET_TABLE VARCHAR, APPLICATION_NAME VARCHAR):VARCHAR(16777216) 
TO ROLE SNF_ADMIN_ROLE COPY CURRENT GRANTS ;

Running this line returns an error because Snowflake expects the above SQL command to look like this:
GRANT OWNERSHIP ON PROCEDURE TESTDB.OPERATIONS.LOG_ETL_STATS( VARCHAR, VARCHAR, VARCHAR, VARCHAR) TO ROLE SNF_ADMIN_ROLE COPY CURRENT GRANTS ;

I have tried a couple of things to try and manipulate the obj.GRANTED_ON string to try and get it into the above format, but nothing has been successful so far, was wondering if anyone else experienced this and has a good solution to returning the procedure/function in a form that snowflake likes?
